# How to get the pixelformat layout using the Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Given an HDC, I would like to figure out not only how many bits of Red, Green, Blue and Alpha there are (using [DescribePixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but even their layout (BGR(A) or RGB(A)) so that I can perform pixel and color component level manipulation.

Should I always assume they're in BGR(A) order? Is that a reasonable assumption?

Comment: On windows little endian machines, I think it is always BGRA whereas big endian is always ARBG iirc. Not sure but I do know that is the convention for OpenGL and many api's using Windows. It is also faster to use BGRA on windows. For this reason, I believe everything is actually BGRA on windows (5% faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449(VS.85).aspx

That's the docs for COLORREF which is stored as 0x00BBGGRR.

According to that which is used by most of WINAPI, I'd have to assume that everything on Windows is actually stored in BGRA format.. AFAIK, DIBs are in BGRA format.

You can try painting a window red. Create a DIB section and copy the pixels into a buffer. If the first byte is 0xFF, it is RGBA otherwise it is BGRA.

GDI32 images always stores as BGRA on my machine. GDI24 images are always BGR. I have released an Image handling API and of all the users, I haven't met a single one that has not had the same format. I have yet to see a DC or default backbuffer format in RGBA instead of BGRA.

What is the reason you really need to know the format of a DC? I never found myself wanting to know.

When reading an image, you figure out the bit count from the BitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount field.

Comment: I need the format of a DC in order to convert the bits of a bitmap captured from that DC into YUV. I am using GetDIBBits but I have seen it return me BGRA or BGR on different machines. For now I check the number of bits in R, G and B using the result of DescribePixelFormat and assume only BGR(A) layout. I'm worried this might not be all on different machines, though. In the absence of functions to get the information I need, I was looking for documented assurance that there wouldn't be, I guess. Going by your experiences with the library, I will accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for the [`PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> iPixelType
>   Specifies the type of pixel data. The following types are defined:
>   PFD_TYPE_RGBA   RGBA pixels. Each pixel has four components in this order: red, green, blue, and alpha.
>   PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX Color-index pixels. Each pixel uses a color-index value.

So it seems like they're either RGBA or indexed.

Comment: Sorry, but nope. All that flags says if the pixelformat is indexed or not. The pixels could physically be BGR or BGRA, or RGB or RGBA. I have seen this flag tell me they're RGBA but they're actually arranged BGRA.

Comment: Well, the docs say "in this order," so perhaps it's an endian issue? Or maybe the docs are simply wrong? Are there any other values you've seen for the `iPixelType` field?